# Strange JSON serialization with FasterXML Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

I don't understand why I get the serialized JSON for the given Class as shown below.

This is a generated class from WSDL, so I cannot change it:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Lawyer")
public class Lawyer extends Person {

    @XmlElementWrapper(required = true)
    @XmlElement(name = "lawyerOffice", namespace = "http://xxx/addressbook/external/v01/types")
    protected List<LawyerOffice> lawyerOffices;     

    public List<LawyerOffice> getLawyerOffices() {
    if (lawyerOffices == null) {
        lawyerOffices = new ArrayList<LawyerOffice>();
    }
    return lawyerOffices;
    }

    public void setLawyerOffices(List<LawyerOffice> lawyerOffices) {
    this.lawyerOffices = lawyerOffices;
    }

}
```

When a class instance gets serialized with fasterxml.jackson, I get:

```
{
    "ID": "e0d62504-4dfb-4c92-b70b-0d411e8ed102",
    "lawyerOffice": [
         {
            ...
         }
     ]
}
```

So the name of the array is **lawyerOffice**. I expect **lawyerOffice*s***.

This is the implementation that I use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This is my ObjectMapper configuration (injected in CXF):

```
@Provider
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json" })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json" })
public class JsonProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {

    public static ObjectMapper createMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    AnnotationIntrospector primary = new DPAJaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory());
    AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
    AnnotationIntrospector pair = AnnotationIntrospector.pair(primary, secondary);
    mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);

    return mapper;

    }

    public JsonProvider() {
    super();

    this.setMapper(createMapper());

    }

}
```

How can I get the "correct" list name?

Comment: Please leave a comment when you down vote so I can adapt the question.

Comment: `@XmlElement(name = "lawyerOffice"` ..., sounds to me like `lawyerOffice` is the 'right' name. That said, given your own answer, you really should really include the original `ObjectMapper` configuration code, because it looks like your problem is actually caused by you explicitly using the JAXB annotation support, which is a pretty important detail to leave out of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I enabled the `USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME` feature option in the objectMapper configuration:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory());
    AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
    AnnotationIntrospector pair = AnnotationIntrospector.pair(primary, secondary);
    mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    ...
    mapper.enable(MapperFeature.USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME); // <-----
    ...
```